# How to save a html content to a file not saving into database

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I'm practising my first html example.

I have `EditProfile.htm` page :

```
<body>
    <div align="center">
        <form id="user-edit-form" action="" method="POST">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Display Name</td>
                    <td>
                        <input id="txtusername" type="text" style="width: 260px" />         
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Real Name</td>
                    <td>
                        <input id="txtrealname" type="text" maxlength="100" style="width: 260px" /> 
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Email</td>
                    <td>
                        <input id="txtmail" type="text" maxlength="100" style="width: 390px" /> 
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Save Profile"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>     
    </div>
</body>
```

Client will fill the `textboxes`, I want all the inputed values will be saved (not by the way saving into sql database), and then the client click on : `ViewProfile.htm` (or .aspx) --> the page will show with all information they given.

Can you give me some solution or advise or link,document to do that.

1. How can I save all the inputed values given by client in `EditProfile.htm` page into a file(xml,...???) in a folder?
2. Then, How can I get the all the information in that new file (xml,...?) to the page: `ViewProfile.htm` when the client want to see they informations.

Comment: Well, you want to do it only with HTML? HTML, can not do that alone, without another client-side languaje, like C++ or VB.NET... HTML is only a server-side languaje...

Comment: html, c# aspx page also

Comment: Which is your C# code?

Comment: If you are using c# then instead of input types use asp:textbox

Comment: Well, you'll need some persistence mechanism. If you only have HTML, you'll have to leverage `localStorage`, `indexedDb`, `WebSQL`, or the `FileSystem API`. Be warned, browser support varies wildly.

Comment: @SidM yes, I will use asp textbox instead of input type. HOw can I save the textbox values and then show it again in another page without saving into database?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass values from one page to another by using querystring, although there are many other ways too

this is my editprofile.aspx page

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div align="center">

            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Display Name</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDisplayName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>         
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Real Name</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtRealName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>         
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Email</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>        
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click"></asp:Button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

    </div>

    </form>
```

In code behind of this page I am passing values via querystring

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Viewprofile.aspx?DisplayName=" + txtDisplayName.Text + "&RealName=" + txtRealName.Text+"&Email="+txtEmail.Text);
    }
```

Now you can get these values on Viewprofile.aspx.cs like this

```
string displayName = Request.QueryString["DisplayName"];
string realName= Request.QueryString["RealName"];
string email= Request.QueryString["Email"];
```

In order to save these values in xml file you can try this

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument( new XElement( "myXML", 
                                           new XElement( "DisplayName", displayName ), 
                                           new XElement( "RealName", realName ),
                                           new XElement( "Email", email)
 )  );
        doc.Save( "D:\\temp.xml" );
```

Comment: thanks, I know it already, can you tell me how I save the displayName, realName, email ???

Comment: you want to save it where?

Comment: I want to save it into a file (may be xml file or...) in a folder in my web project

Comment: thanks again, one more question, how about get information from xml file to asp Label???

Comment: @VyClarks for that you need to post another question and after seeing your xml then only i can give you the right answer instead of telling you try this or try that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39562/discussion-between-sid-m-and-vy-clarks)